# .htaccess dynamic to static URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make my dynamic URL's into static looking URL's.
This is a typical URL that I now have: 
`http://www.somedomain.com/design/index.php?p=about`

I would like it to be: `http://www.somedomain.com/about`

So far, I've gotten it to look like this: `http://www.somedomain.com/design/about.html`

This is the Rewriterule I'm using: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]`

How would I modify it so it would look like this: `http://www.somedomain.com/about`?

Thanks for any/all help!!!
Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using rewrite rules to give 'static' URI is **NEVER** a good idea.

A few other ideas you can use:

- Make the 'about' page a directory (folder) with a file called `index.php` or `index.html` in it. This way the URL shows http://example.com/about/ and the information you wish can still be displayed as needed.
- Use the `POST` method instead of `GET` methods. This will display as http://example.com/about.php (*Note: there is no `?` or other parameters behind that.*)
- Utilize both methods to give a 'seamless' URI on page transitions.

Comment: My current index.php dynamically loads info now from other directories and a database. So, using a different folder for each page probably wouldn't work for my situation.

Comment: PenguinCoder, you might not think it a good idea but it is extremely common practice and with the trend to "SEO optimised" URIs it is becoming more so.  This isn't a mainstream view, so it might be better to qualify such sweeping statements with "in my opinion" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rick, you're on the right track.  You need to read the Apache rewrite documentation.  For your `docroot/.htaccess` start it with:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase   /
```

Then generalised version of your rule:

```
 Rewrite Rule ^(\w+)$     index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite any requests which are for a word string to `index.php`.  You need to be aware that the rewrite engine rescans the `.htaccess` file if a match has occured so you need to make sure that you don't create a loop.  In this case the replacement string has a "`.`" in it and the pattern doesn't, so this won't occur, but for more complex cases you may need to 'guard' the rules with one or more `RewriteCond` statements.  Again, read the Apache documentation.