# .htaccess from dynamic page url to static

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to create a dynamic rule of the .htaccess to redirect the page from:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/index.php?id=11&title=my-page-title
```

to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/11/my-page-title
```

Where:
 - id is an integer number
 - title is string

I found on stack overflow a similar example but only with a single `$_GET` value and not with [.htaccess dynamic to static URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402335/htaccess-dynamic-to-static-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have worded this is actually wrong.  What you want to do is to route incoming requests such as:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/11/my-page-title
```

To the script at `/subdir/index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)$ /subdir/index.php?id=$1$title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Note that this particular approach will redirect everything on your server of `*/*` format.  If you need to make exceptions such as for static files or only want certain patterns to redirect, you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: I have the index.php that manage the pages stored in a database (in a table I have the columns id, title, ... , html), and I would like to create a rule to make the entire website more SEO-friendly. I've tried to add some exceptions like the includes directories and all seem to work properly

Comment: Could you kindly explain me the meaning of "[L,QSA]" ?

Comment: @Danilo The `L` flag means to treat this as the last rule in the file. In other process this rule and nothing else that follows it.  This is top prevent any additional rewrites which may change the desired result.  The `QSA` flag is a query string append, so say you still wanted to pass URL parameters in to your "clean" URL.  This would take any such parameters passed and add them on to the end of the redirected URL.

Comment: With Code-Igniter 2 I had to redirect any not found files/directories to index.php and then add a route in `application/config/routes.php` that redirects to my controller's method. I attempted to solve it in `.htaccess` only but that didn't work. Only with the route + non-existing redirects to `index.php/$1` did work.

Comment: So what I means is: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`. + route in said config file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this here:

```
RewriteRule /([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+) subdir/index.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

This rule will look for a number with at least 1 diget and a lower case string which can contain minus signs, this could be `a` or just `-` too.